# Subclassing ActiveRecord with permalink_fu in a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-engines, permalink-fu

This question is related to extending class methods in Ruby, perhaps more specifically in the way that permalink_fu does so.

It appears that `has_permalink` on a model will not be available in a derived model. Certainly I would expect anything defined in a class to be inherited by its derived classes.

```
class MyScope::MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_permalink :name
end

class MyClass < MyScope::MyClass
  unloadable
  #has_permalink :name # This seems to be required
end
```

Is there something in the way permalink_fu mixes itself in that causes this issue?

I'm using the permalink-v.1.0.0 gem http://github.com/goncalossilva/permalink_fu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this, I can now see that the problem is related to how permalink_fu verifies it it should create a permalink or not. It verifies this by checking if the permalink_field of the class is blank or not.

What's the permalink_field? When you do

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :name
end

class Child < Parent
end
```

you can access the permalink by writing `Parent.new.permalink` or `Child.new.permalink`. This method name can be changed by writing

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_permalink :name 'custom_permalink_name'
end
```

If so, the permalink will be accessible by writing `Parent.new.custom_permalink_name` (or `Child.new.custom_permalink_name`).

What's the problem with this? The permalink_field accessor methods are defined on `Parent`'s metaclass:

```
class << self
  attr_accessor :permalink_field
end
```

When you run the has_permalink method, it calls `Parent.permalink_field = 'permalink'`.

The problem is that although the `permalink_field` **method** is available on all subclasses, its **value** is stored on the class it was called. This means that the value is not propagated to the subclasses.

So, as the `permalink_field` is stored on the `Parent` class, the Child does not inherit the value, although it inherits the accessor methods. As `Child.permalink_field` is blank, the `should_create_permalink?` returns `false`, and `Child.create :name => 'something'` does not create a permalink.

A possible solution would be to replace the attr_acessors on the metaclass with cattr_accessors on the class (lines 57 to 61 on the permalink_fu.rb file).

Replace

```
class << base
  attr_accessor :permalink_options
  attr_accessor :permalink_attributes
  attr_accessor :permalink_field
end
```

with

```
base.cattr_accessor :permalink_options
base.cattr_accessor :permalink_attributes
base.cattr_accessor :permalink_field
```

Note that this will invalidate any possible customization on the subclass. You will no longer be able to specify different options for the subclasses, as these three attributes are shared by `Parent` and all its subclasses (and subsubclasses).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it definitely gets me started on a fix.